# property page customization for dropdown list in alfresco 5.0 d

Tags: alfresco-share

i am having multiple field sets in alfresco document property page, and i want to show only one at a time based on the value i will select from drop down.
can you please help me to achieve it on my alfresco property page.

Its really on high priority.

please suggest me something to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this [tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/archives/2012/02/27/1555).

In this case, the property is for profile page. You have two examples: "Shirt Size" and "Likes Neil Diamond?"

Let me know if it results.

Comment: I just want to display some fields dynamically based on value that user will select from drop down. Suppose i have one drop down list with value a and b, and later i have 2 textfields. now here my requirment is if user will select value a then first textfield will get enabled. and if user will select b value from dropdown, then second text field should be enabled. is it possible to do like this??? 

Thanks.